# Unlocked Record in SharePoint Online using Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a SharePoint Online library where I have applied a retention label which sets document Record Status to Locked, we can Unlock the document by changing it's Status to Unlocked which is a manual process. Is there any way in Power Automate to unlock the record status and then lock it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my knowledge, Power Automate has no direct action to update "Retention label" column for now. You can upvote the idea [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/Get-and-Set-Compliance-Labels-in-SharePoint/idi-p/156112) so MS can get you thoughts.